# Change default login URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to change default login URL redirection when unauthenticated use tries to access a page. Basically it redirects to `/login` but I want it to `'/'` 
I am using the default laravel Auth which is created by `php artisan make:auth`. I just want to redirect to other URL when it's unauthenticated user.

Note: I'm at Laravel 5.6

Comment: Where and how did you try to change it? What error did you get?

Comment: No error i'm getting. Suppose i'm an unauthenticated user and trying to access /home . which is only accessible if i'm am logged in otherwise it redirects to '/login'. i want to redirect it to '/' not 'login' as i have put the login page in '/' route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With default `auth` scaffolding Laravel will redirect to a route named `login`.

**Option 1**

Put this in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

// ... Other stuff

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest('/');
}
```

Put your desired url in `redirect()->guest('/');`

**Option 2**

Rename the route you want to redirect to to `login`:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'login';
})->name('login');
```

And change the form action from `route('login')` to `/login` in `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
```

Comment: Sorry there is a problem with your solution.  The fact is if i used your solution i can't submit the default login form. As login is redirected to '/' which is get request. But mine is post while submitting the form. 
Get and POST both are 'login' route only in default Laravel auth.

Comment: There, edited. This will work, just make sure to remove the `login` name. Or you could rename Laravel's `POST`  login route to something like `postLogin` and change the form action from `route('login')` to `route('postLogin')`